# Can you please provide test class for this

Tags: apex, code-coverage, scheduled-apex

```java
global class LastLoginEmailJObs implements Schedulable {
   global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails =  new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for(User u : [SELECT Id, LastLoginDate, Email FROM User]) { //You can add filter for active users only
            If( u.LastLoginDate <= System.today().addDays(-1)){
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
                mail.setToAddresses(new List<String> { u.Email });
                mail.setTargetObjectId('User ID'); 
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support'); 
                mail.setUseSignature(false); 
                mail.setBccSender(false); 
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(false); 
                EmailTemplate et = [Select Id from EmailTemplate where Name = 'Users_Please_login']; 
                mail.setTemplateId(et.Id); 
                mails.add(mail);
           }
        }
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please do not ask the SFSE community to write code on your behalf - check out [help/on-topic] for more guidelines, and learn about [ask] to get the most out of this community.

Answer (score 0):

Before writing a unit test, you need to fix your code. See the comments below.

```
global class LastLoginEmailJobs implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails =  new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        // Don't query in a loop; we'll move it here.
        EmailTemplate et = [Select Id from EmailTemplate where Name = 'Users_Please_login']; 
        // Use a filter instead of the if statement for performance reasons.
        for(User u : [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE (LastLoginDate < LAST_N_DAYS:1 OR LastLoginDate = NULL) AND IsActive = true]) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
            // Don't use toAddresses to email users, as this is rate limited daily.
            // mail.setToAddresses(new List<String> { u.Email });
            mail.setTargetObjectId(u.Id); 
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support'); 
            mail.setUseSignature(false); 
            mail.setBccSender(false); 
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false); 
            mail.setTemplateId(et.Id); 
            mails.add(mail);
        }
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
    }
}
```

Aside from that, we add a filter to check for LastLoginDate over a day ago, or that have *never* logged in. Here's the trick; we're going to just create a new User, then run the class:

```
User u = new User(); // fill in all required details here
insert u;
Test.startTest();
System.scheduleJob('Testing Job', '0 0 * * * ?', new LastLoginEmailJobs());
Test.stopTest();
```